# How to write conditional query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I came from MSSQL and I'm trying to learn MySQL.
Documentation seem to not help me.

I don't want my query to start always with SELECT, I want my query to SELECT, INSERT or UPDATE depending on the condition. I can't seem to do it with MySQL. Here is my code:

```
    IF COALESCE((SELECT 1 FROM gt_postmeta WHERE meta_value = '12345' LIMIT 1), 0) THEN 
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO gt_posts ( 
            post_date, 
            post_content, 
            post_title, 
            post_name, 
            post_type ) 
        VALUES ( 
            '', 
            '0000493729150.jpg', 
            'SHAMROCK', 
            '', 
            ''); 

        SET @parent_id = (SELECT id FROM gt_posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);

        INSERT INTO gt_postmeta(
            post_id, 
            meta_key, 
            meta_value) 
        VALUES
            (@parent_id, '_visibility', 'visible'), 
            (@parent_id, '_price', 'H72 SEMI-GLOSS DARK EARTH'), 
            (@parent_id, '_regular_price', 'H72 SEMI-GLOSS DARK EARTH'), 
            (@parent_id, '_sku', '12345'); 

        INSERT INTO gt_warehouse(
            warehouse_id, 
            stock, 
            product_sku) 
        VALUES(
            '178', 
            '', 
            '12345'); 
    END; 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        IF COALESCE((SELECT 1 FROM gt_warehouse WHERE product_sku = '12345' AND warehouse_id = '178' LIMIT 1), 0) THEN 
        BEGIN 
            UPDATE 
                gt_warehouse SET stock = '' 
            WHERE product_sku = '12345' 
            AND warehouse_id = '178'; 
        END; 
        ELSE 
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO gt_warehouse( 
                warehouse_id, 
                stock, 
                product_sku) 
            VALUES (
                '', 
                '', 
                '', 
                '12345'); 
        END; 
        END IF; 
    END; 
END IF;
```

Comment: Please edit your statement so it's not all on one line. It's unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow**: You must do the following things to perform this task in `MYSQL`

1- you have use `STORED PROCEDURE` in `MYSQL` to set query block as package exactly as in `SQL SERVER` but syntax is bit different

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_report`(
------
------
)
BEGIN
--Query block with condition
END;
```

2- You don't need `COALESCE` to check the existence of value, you can simply use `EXISTS` (`LIMIT` is also optional)

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM gt_postmeta WHERE meta_value = '12345') THEN
```

3- After this you may get minor issues like proper use of `semicolon`, `BEGIN` & `END` which you can resolve by yourself.

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT id, login, ( IF(requires='privacy-weight',0,privacy-weight) ) AS privacy-weight, requires
FROM [mytable]
WHERE [mywhereclause]
```

For more information on how the IF function works in MySQL see the docs at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html

Comment: I'm not restricted to select only am I?